# How can I declare a variable so that it will hold its value and can be accessible from any class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, scope

My Projects contains multiple classes each has its own separate .h and .cpp file .
I want to declare a variable use so that I can access/modify its value from any of the classes .

Comment: declare the classes in the same namespace, have a global variable in namespace

Comment: @ForeverStudent: Namespaces have nothing to do with anything.

Comment: Be aware that the use of global variables is generally frowned upon. There are good reasons to use them, but not as many as you might think.

Comment: @ForeverStudent could you plz give some example thankyou

Comment: @DevSolar Is there any way do the mentioned

Comment: That's not good encapsulation.  Sounds like a poor design to me.

Comment: I think Kerrek answered your question correctly. For hints about avoiding globals (which gets more and more important the larger the program gets) provide more information and ask at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

You can add another translation unit to define a variable at namespace scope and make it accessible by providing a declaration:

**var.h:**

```
extern int a;
```

**var.cpp:**

```
#include "var.h"

int a = 15;
```

Now every translation unit in your program can `#include "var.h"` and use `a`.

It may be sensible to a) give the variable a meaningful, unambiguous name, and b) place it in a named namespace.

Comment: While this is the correct literal answer it would benefit from hints about alternatives (the OP may think he needs a global but not in fact need it). Static members (which is admittedly basically a namespace) or better member functions, possibly singletons, etc.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: That belongs on Code Review.

Comment: "How do programs get the right data in the right place at the right time" is too broad for a single question, and we have no details that could narrow it down, so I agree that answers shouldn't be expected to provide design hints. There's no general silver bullet for mutable globals. Well, "dependency injection", but that just begs the question of how to apply it to the questioner's code.

Comment: @KerrekSB Why so? The question is very broad and providing alternatives might help future readers with similar needs. You know, [optimizing for pearls, not for sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) and all.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger: Yes, but for every voice like yours there's a dissenting voice screaming "just answer the damn question" :-) The point is, we have existing facilities for code review. The OP can simply take this approach, write it up and then post it on Code Review for design feedback. I don't need to shoulder all that here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a public static variable in one of your classes or you can be naughty and declare a global variable outside of all your classes in one module and then use the extern keyword to reference it in other modules.

C++ is a hybrid OOP language: you don't have to use classes all the time. If you do that, be ready to get flamed by self-righteous programmers and StackOverflow lurkers.

Comment: A public static data member of a class is no better or worse than a global outside any class, as far as getting flamed is concerned.

Comment: @SteveJessop: a public static is at least part of a class and has some measure of encapsulation. It's OOP. A classless global is, like, original C from 1974. The flame level is completely different because most programmers these days went straight to C++ without learning C.

Comment: It's just using a class as a namespace. Either way you have a mutable global, which may get you flamed (by which I mean, it can easily lead to certain problems that the questioner will discover in time, and some people are itching to warn others away from those problems). To me that's not related to the main principles of OOP, but YMMV.

Comment: @nicomp what is the best practice , I just want to exchange the data between classes

Comment: @Abhishek : The best practice is to practice the OOP principles of Data Hiding and Encapsulation, in this case implemented as a Singleton design pattern. And I know I will get flamed for suggesting a Singleton.